# Does it hurt to have multiple .htaccess_backup files?

Tags: seo, htaccess, backups

Today I saw .htaccess_backup files in my file manager.

[image]

Does it affect SEO or something else? Should I delete all the .htaccess_backup files or does it not matter?

Comment: No, but add them to robots.txt as disallow.
Disallow: /.htaccess.....

Answer (score 2):

If the files are available from the web, this may be a vulnerability, since it shows part of your configuration to the world. This should not be a serious vulnerability for an otherwise correctly configured server; consider whether the presence of various paths in the file inform someone that those paths exist where they would otherwise not be noticed.

This won’t have any effect on SEO — that’s not what SEO is about. There is no user benefit or detriment to these additional files placed on a server not providing content, so search engines are not interested in this.

Comment: The files shown should not be available to the web. The apache pattern is .ht* by default. Backing up .htaccess files this way is quite common. Cheers!!

Comment: Even if Apache were configured to allow them to be served, it would be difficult to guess the exact file names.  It looks like they have unix timestamps on the end of them which corresponds to the second at which they were created.  As long you don't show a directory index for that directory, or *cough* post a screenshot with the filenames on the internet, it would not be easy to probe for the vulnerability by guessing the exact second that the backup was created.